# Redirecting a URL in playframework

Tags: redirect, playframework-2.0

My AJAX code is producing a following GET request in the play framework

```
'GET /localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/proxy?url=http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&EXCEPTIONS=application/vnd.ogc.se_xml&BBOX=-74.084108,40.737824,-73.862875,40.817377&X=656&Y=271&INFO_FORMAT=text/html&QUERY_LAYERS=tiger:tiger_roads&FEATURE_COUNT=50&Layers=tiger:tiger_roads&Styles=&Srs=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=1168&HEIGHT=420&format=image/png'
```

I want the above request to be redirected to **/localhost/geoserver** in the route file or the controller file.Can anybody help me in achieving the above objective?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [redirect](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.2.4/play/mvc/Controller.html#redirect%28java.lang.String%29) method in the controller to achieve this.

`redirect(url);`

Comment: How to get the current url for it? I'm using Play 2.0.3. There are methods in 1.x version for getting the current url but I cannot figure it out for 2.0.3.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to achieve any redirection, you just need to modify your *routes* file. If you have

```
GET    /link1     Application.Controller1
```

in your routes file, and if you hit `http://localhost:9000/link1`, this will cause Controller1(in your Application.java file) method to run. If you want to return any html stuff after the execution of this controller(this might be a whole div/span/table/paragraph/etc. and you can place it into your html at runtime), you need to use `renderHtml("<>...</>")`. What' s more, if you want to run this controller and place the html into the page you are currently showing via JavaScript-Jquery, you need to use something like;

```
$.load("/link1", {parameter1:"the value"}, function(result){
    $("#div1").html(result);
});
```

You can achieve any redirection and implement any kind of AJAX requests this way.

To redirect from controller, you can simply call `redirect(another_page)`, or you can call the static controller methods like `index(param)` (that is defined in your controller class)

To get the current URL, play provides [@request.path](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.3/api/java/play/mvc/Http.RequestHeader.html#path%28%29)